# issue with insert query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, last-insert-id

I have following query :

```
insert into A select last_insert_id(),B.id,C.name,C.address,
from sample_table C join other_table B on B.phoneNumber=C.phoneNumber;
```

I am getting duplicate primary key value =1 error ( which should be generated by last_insert_id() ). 
Here is the structure of tables

```
A
id|phoneNumber|name|address
---------------------------

B
id|phoneNumber|email
--------------------

C
id|phoneNumber|name|address
---------------------------
```

Could someone please help me why last_insert_id() is always returning 1.

More Info: id field in table A,B and C are auto_increamented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you know `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed column's inserted value.and `NULL` for `AUTO_INCREMENT` forces generating new value. what if you use NULL rather than last_insert_id():

```
INSERT INTO A 
SELECT NULL, B.id,C.name,C.address,
FROM sample_table C JOIN other_table B ON B.phoneNumber=C.phoneNumber;
```

Is there any reason you must use last_insert_id()? or just question?

Comment: just used NULL and it seems to be working. Lets the query finish.

Comment: honestly I did not know about using NULL and know this difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this multiple times, did you mean to insert last_insert_id() + 1?

If you're not running this multiple times, then it sounds like table A already has a PK of 1, and you need to pick a different value for a.id or update the existing row.

Also, last_insert_id() returns the last inserted primary key **for an auto-increment column**.  If A.id IS NOT an auto-increment column, then last_insert_id will not change value on inserts to A.  If A.id IS an auto-increment column, then you don't need to include it in your insert anyways.

**Edit 2:** See below

```
insert into A 
select null, B.phonenumber,C.name,C.address,
from sample_table C 
join other_table B 
  on B.phoneNumber=C.phoneNumber;
```

Comment: it does not matter because then it will keep returning 2

Comment: I disagree.  The first time the script runs, last_insert_id() will return 1.  The next time, it will return 2, because that will be the last inserted PK value.

Comment: and that is what I am trying to say sir that no matter how many time it run it is returning 1 always.

Comment: @Ashish With `last_insert_id()` (not `+1`), then it will always return 1, yes.

Comment: Also, the value of last_insert_id() is always constant in a single statement with multiple inserts.  In other words, if you copy and paste the same insert 5 times and execute all 5 inserts in a single statement, then you'll get the same value for last_insert_id() for all instances of that insert within your statement, which will throw an error.  In stored procedures, the behavior is different, and last_insert_id() will always be the last inserted auto_increment id.

Comment: even for +1 it is giving same error Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I have seen your answer first the column is auto increment, second how insert is going to decide not to put phonenumber in ID and that is what happening if I remove last_insert_id()

Comment: @Ashish Are you inserting the `last_insert_id()` just becuase you don't want `B.id` to be stored as `A.id`, but instead you want `B.id` stored as `A.phoneNumber`? If so, look at the [syntax of `INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), specifically the `VALUES` part.